# Context Module set default block

Tags: blocks, 7

I am looking to have a subfooter that I can toggle with all types of rich content based on the page that visitors are on.  I would like to be able to say the homepage has this block, the blog section has this block, and so on.  I have quite a few uncategorized pages that I would like to be caught in a 'default' block of some form.  The issue is, if I have a default, it will show two if a condition is met with another context.  I would prefer to avoid the use of php snippits in blocks if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude other contexts. In the default (sitewide?) context, add a Condition: Context, and use the ~ character to exclude the specific contexts that should not be in effect.

E.g., `~rich_subfoot` (if rich_subfoot is the name of the context providing the rich subfooter content)

Comment: Great, works for me!  It's just a lot of work to keep up with many modules.  I was hoping there was a simple way without having to write a module.